# Mostrar Valores do DBF acima dos pontos MapWinGis + Delphi

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-xe8

Possuo o seguinte codigo para abrir um arquivo .shp e plotar o mesmo em um componente do `MapWinGis` Map1.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var shp: Shapefile;
 HandleLayer: integer;
begin
  shp:= CoShapefile.Create;
  shp.Open ('C:\Users\Documents\BD Demo\Alta Cruz\cruz\alta_cruz.shp', nil) ;
  Map1.Focused;
  HandleLayer:= Map1.AddLayer (shp, true);
  Map1.ZoomToMaxExtents;
```

E um codigo bem parecido para abrir o arquivo de pontos:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var shp: Shapefile;
 HandleLayer: integer;
begin
  shp:= CoShapefile.Create;
  shp.Open ('C:\Users\Desktop\opa\Win32\Debug\Amostragem.shp', nil) ;
  Map1.Focused;
  HandleLayer:= Map1.AddLayer (shp, true);
  Map1.ZoomToMaxExtents;
  shp.StartEditingShapes(true, null);
```

e como resultado tenho isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que eu precisava era ler o Arquivo .dbf do arquivo de amostragem, e exibir os pontos como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O exemplo acima foi feito o gis; **QGIS**

é possível fazer igual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não conheço essa sua área e também não trabalhei com o MapWinGis.

Para abrir um arquivo DBF (Arquivo de Dados do FoxPro), você precisa de criar uma conexão com esse banco de dados.

Você pode usar o componente TADOConnection, e a **String de Conexão** (ConnectionString)= "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=c:\mydbpath;" onde **mydbpath** é o caminho para a pasta onde está o seu arquivo DBF. Tipo o que você usou no .open(''). Altere também a propriedade LoginPrompt para False.

Para ler o arquivo DFB, você vai precisar de um componente, TADOQuery, definir na propriedade Connection o TADOConnection que você adicionou antes. Defina na propriedade SQL a seguinte consulta:

```
Select * from <arquivodbf>
```

Para conseguir ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo você pode utilizar o seguinte código (Veja as observaçoes após o código):

```
ADOConnection1.Connected:= True;
ADOQuery1.Open;
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
  begin
  memo1.Lines.Add(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Codigo').Value);
  ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOConnection1.Connected:= False;
```

Observações:
ADOConnection1 é o meu TADOConnection
ADOQuery1 é a TADOQuery
memo1 é o local para onde estou jogando o valor que li nos campos, você deve adaptar a sua necessidade.

Já trabalhei muito com arquivos DBF, caso precise, nós vamos conversando e alterando a resposta até resolver seu problema.

Abraços!

Deus nos Abençoe!

Comment: Desculpe a demora, tive um problema pessoal, queria poder te dado a recompensa.
Funcionou certinho eu ler o dbf, agora é ajeitar para mostrar no mapa.

Comment: Kra não preocupa bom é que funcionou e agora você esta novamente em produção com seu projeto! Abraços!

Comment: Aproveitando, como eu libero o dbf após usa-lo?

Comment: É, eu estava lendo essa sua pergunta no outro tópico. Pra mim você fez tudo certo. Fechou seu AdoQuery, depois fechou a conexão. Pode parecer meio extremo, mas já pensou em, invés de usar o componente no seu formulário, criar o AdoQuery junto da sua função ? Você poderia destruí-lo e recriá-lo sempre que fosse necessário. O problema do arquivo ficar em uso, tem haver com a existência do componente. Bem, já passei por isso e foi assim que resolvi o meu problema.

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigado amigo.